# How to insert a date value stored in another table and increment it by x days?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a PostgreSQL database and have one table "event_date" with "started_at" (`DATE` format, e.g. '2019-10-29') values which are also the PRIMARY KEY in this table.

Now I want to insert this "started_at" value in another table "event_days" but increasing the date by x days.

Can someone explain how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an INSERT with a SELECT:

```
insert into other_table (started_at, location, moderator)
select started_at + 42, 'Hall 5', 'Tom'
from event_days;
```

`+ 42` add 42 days to the date value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So increasing DATE values by default is days? And if I want to increase it by years for example I need that INTERVAL parameter?

Comment: @burnie: correct I have also added an example on how to deal with additional columns

Comment: And thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name for your quick response! I'm still at the beginning of learning how to deal with databases and SQL and all that stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you really need  insert the related  record  you could use a insert select

```
insert into event_days(started_at, location , moderator)
select  started_at   + interval '10 day',  'hall 5' , 'Tom' 
from  event_date
```

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the quick answer. But I have another problem now. The table event_days has two other columns (location and moderator) that must be filled (NOT NULL). How to write this INSERT with the date + x days and e.g. 'hall 5' and 'Tom' for location and moderator? Sorry, I know I'm a newbie and have to learn a lot.

Comment: Oh, that's easy, I thought it would be more complicated. Thanks a lot @scaisEdge!